# ORDERING POSTS USING COMMENTS COUNT FOR EACH IN RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to display comments based on number of comments as I want to modify @posts to order by number of comments and thanks alot
Post MODEL

```
has_many :comments
```

Posts controller

```
@posts = Post.all
```

COMMENT MODEL :

```
belongs_to :post
```

COMMENT CONTROLLER

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
@comment = @post.comments.order("CREATED_AT DESC")
```

Comment: Are you trying to display *posts* based on number of comments?

Comment: Either use an aggregator function `@posts = Post.left_outer_joins(:comments).select('posts.*, count(comments.*) as comments_count').group(:id).order(comments_count: :desc)` or add `comments_count` [counter cache to posts] (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-counter-cache) and use `@posts = Post.order(comments_count: :desc)`

Comment: yes @robertoplancarte that's what i am trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails has `counter_cache` to help with this. You can read about it [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to)

There are two steps to this

1. Add a comments_cout column to your posts table

`rails g migration AddCommentsCountToPosts comments_count:integer`

`rake db:migrate`

2. Add the counter_cache option to the comments belongs_to relationship

`class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post, counter_cache: true
end`

`class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
end`

Then you can sort by comments_count on the `PostsController` `index` action

`@posts = Post.order(:comments_count)`

Comment: thanks for your answer but counter cache responds to `size` method and I want it to order according to `count` method as when i try to do `post.comments.size`  i get 0 but when i do `post.comments.count` i get a certain number representing the count of the comments so long story short I tried it and it didn't order the posts ...

Comment: This seems like it should work. Did you reset/seed your db?

Comment: NOW AFTER DOING A RESET, IT WORKS LIKE A CHARM